# Why cant I write text?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, algorithm

I have been trying to get this to work for the last three hours, and I need your help now. I simply want to record the text from my editText when the user clicks "done":

```
  e.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            Log.v(TAG, "KEYCODE: " +keyCode);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" +keyCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if ((keyCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {

                Log.v(TAG, "DONE!");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" +e.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here is the XML:

```
   <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"

        />
```

The problem is that my `onKey` is not even displaying any toasts, and I am unable to get the user input when they click done. I have tried changing so many things in my if statement, but now even the `onKey` is not getting called. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why your code is not working is answered in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html).

> Key presses on soft input methods are not required to trigger the
>   methods in this listener, and are in fact discouraged to do so. The
>   default android keyboard will not trigger these for any key to any
>   application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only deliver it
>   for some key presses to applications targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or
>   earlier.

If you are trying to get the user input when they click done, you can try something like

```
e.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you solved my problem I was stuck for a couple of hours. Then what is onKeyListener supposed to be used for?

Comment: Again from the docs `it should only be used for cases where an application has its own on-screen keypad and also wants to process hard keyboard events to match it`. So am guessing when you make a custom keyboard, then maybe this could be used to match to the keyboard events.

Comment: If I want to hide the keyboard after they click done, I can just return false, right?